# Error resolving template [/], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using spring boot 2.2.2, with old spring and dependencies it worked, and now the same code does not work

```
package com.project.productapp.controller;

import com.project.productapp.service.ProductService;
import com.project.productapp.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@Controller
public class ProductController {

@Autowired
ProductService productService;

@Autowired
private UserRepository repository;

@GetMapping(path = "/products")
public String getProducts(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("products", repository.findAll());
    return "product";
}

@GetMapping(path = "/logout")
public String logout(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
    request.logout();
    return "/";
}
}
```

Neither, getProducts or logout does not work. If I set breakpoint, it is hit. I am requesting it using browser, going to http://localhost:8081/logout

Error:

> Thu Mar 19 11:58:45 CET 2020 There was an unexpected error
>   (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). Error resolving template
>   [/], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the
>   configured Template Resolvers
>   org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving
>   template [/], template might not exist or might not be accessible by
>   any of the configured Template Resolvers  at
>   org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:869)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607)
>     at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)   at
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)    at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362)
>     at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)

product.ftl is located correctly (in logout funtion it is not even needed)

[image: http://localhost:8081/logout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

I am trying to display **product.ftl**, and that **extension is not defaultly supported anymore**, based on this website http://zetcode.com/springboot/freemarker/ .It worked for me some time ago, because I used old Spring boot version. In newer ones **.ftlh** extension is used as default now.

The fix is to set freemarker suffix in **application.properties** as following:

```
spring.freemarker.suffix=.ftl
```

If you will have trouble with this setting recognition, in **pom.xml**, following dependency should be sufficient

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf dependency that I used caused me some problems, so delete it if neccessary.